# c# pass class as a parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, elasticsearch, asp.net-mvc-5, nest

I want to pass a class as parameter.

So what I want to do is the pass a class, for example: "Customer" to a method.
I want to do this because then I can also pass, for example: "Contract" as class to the same method. This way I don't need to make a method for every class.

Side info: I am using EntityFramework 6, MVC 5, Nest 1.0 and ElasticSearch 1.4

The concept is that we place stuff in ElasticSearch and that we then can do a search.
The search query is:

```
SearchElasticClient.Search<Customer>(body => body
                              .AllIndices()
                              .Size(500)
                              .Query(query => query
                                  .Bool(@bool => @bool
                                      .Must(must => must
                                          .QueryString(qs => qs
                                              .Query("XXXX"))))));
```

And for contract:

```
SearchElasticClient.Search<Contract>(body => body
                              .AllIndices()
                              .Size(500)
                              .Query(query => query
                                  .Bool(@bool => @bool
                                      .Must(must => must
                                          .QueryString(qs => qs
                                              .Query("XXXX"))))));
```

As you can see, if I want to do a search for every type we have, then I need to copy paste this query like 20 times at least.

I don't like copy pasting because the code is not proper and when I need to change it, it will be a lot of work.

So I want to create a method that takes my class as argument or something like that so that I can make a generic method that reuses this block of code.

So for our example:

**My (Enitity Framework) classes:**

```
public class Customer{
    public int CustomerID {get;set;}
    public String CustomerName {get;set;}
}

public class Contract{
    public int ContractID {get;set;}
    public String ContractName {get;set;}
}
```

*relation(s) between the classes is for me irrelavent so I left them out.*

**Then in my HomeController I would like something like**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  ...

     public ActionResult Search(String textToSearch)
    {
        //So here you see that I want to use the same method for both classes.
        Customer customer = Helpers.SearchHelper.Search(textToSearch);
        Contract contract = Helpers.SearchHelper.Search(textToSearch);
    }
}
```

**Then my SearchHelper would be something like:**

```
public static class SearchHelper
{
     public static ElasticClient SearchElasticClient
        {
            get
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
                var setting = new ConnectionSettings(uri, "default_INDEX");
                return new ElasticClient(setting);
            }
        }

        public static void SearchTest(String textToSearch, MyClass)
        {
            var test = SearchElasticClient
                            .Search<Customer>(body => body
                              .AllIndices()
                              .Size(500)
                              .Query(query => query
                                  .Bool(@bool => @bool
                                      .Must(must => must
                                          .QueryString(qs => qs
                                              .Query("XXXX"))))));

        }
}
```

As you can see, now I set my class "Customer" fixed in my code.
I want to replace that with a variable or something.

**Now what I have tried**:

```
    public static void SearchTest<T>(String textToSearch)
    {
        var test = SearchElasticClient
                        .Search<T>(body => body
                          .AllIndices()
                          .Size(500)
                          .Query(query => query
                              .Bool(@bool => @bool
                                  .Must(must => must
                                      .QueryString(qs => qs
                                          .Query("XXXX"))))));

    }
```

Here I get the compile error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nest.ISearchRequest' because it is not a delegate type."

I am not familiar with delegation and how it works and if I can use it, so if delegation is something I need, please provide me enough details.

I also tried:

```
    public static void SearchTest(String textToSearch, Type myClass)
    {
        var test = SearchElasticClient
                        .Search<myClass>(body => body
                          .AllIndices()
                          .Size(500)
                          .Query(query => query
                              .Bool(@bool => @bool
                                  .Must(must => must
                                      .QueryString(qs => qs
                                          .Query("XXXX"))))));

    }
```

Then it gives me the compile error: "The Type or namespace 'myClass' could not be found." I understand why I get this error, so I know that it will be more something like public static void Search(..){..} but I have no idea how to implement it.

I hope this is a better explanation about my problem.

So it is an implemantion of the "Nest" search and I want to avoid copy pasting the search query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pass instances of the class not the class its self.

Comment: @WindRaven But he doesn't want to send instances of the class; he only wants to provide the method with a type, rather than an instance.

Comment: @Servy  Now the code is making more sense.  Generics would be the way to go but with the lamda it wont work quite right.  More information on the exact use case will be helpful here, What are you trying to search for and would it be possible to use reflection.

Comment: I am now out of office but I understand that my question is not clear. ik willen created/update the question with more details and better examples.thanks everyone For the comments and sorry for the bad description

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to do is make `Search` generic

```
public static classToPass Search<classToPass>()
```

Then use it like this

```
Test x = Helper.Search<Test>(); //Test = class as definied above
TestTwo y = Helper.Search<TestTwo>();
```

Comment: I tried that but it won't compile because of the lambda :s

Comment: @Boeykes You should create a new question about how to get the code in your method to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `Search` method generic.  A generic argument is, more or less, a parameter that is a type, rather than an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static object Search<T>(T classToPass)
    {
        SearchElasticClient
                              .Search<T>(body => body
                                .AllIndices()
                                .Size(500)
                                .Query(query => query
                                    .Bool(@bool => @bool
                                        .Must(must => must
                                            .QueryString(qs => qs
                                                .Query("XXX"))))));

    }
}
```